# Counterexample to "if $f:A\to A$ induces the identity $\hat f:\operatorname{Spec}(A)\to\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, then $f=\operatorname{id}_A$"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Does anyone know any example that invalidates the following affirmation:

> If a morphism $f:A\to A$ induces the identity $\hat f:\operatorname{Spec} \left( A \right) \to \operatorname{Spec} \left( A \right)$ then $f = \operatorname{id} _A $.

Comment: Take $A$ to be a field. This is not research-level.

Comment: No, nobody knows such an example that would invalidate a true assertion!

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  Do you mean to assume that $\hat{f}$ is the identity on the *topological space* $Spec(A)$ or on the *scheme* $Spec(A)$?  If the former, your "affirmation" is false; if the latter, it's true.

Comment: To sum up the answers: If $f,g : A \to B$ are homomorphisms of commutative rings, such that $\tilde{f} =\tilde{g}$ *as morphisms of schemes*, then $f=g$. But it does *not* suffice to assume that $\tilde{f}=\tilde{g}$ *as continuous maps*. In other words, it depends on which *category* you are working with.

Answer (score 5):

Let us recall that the category of affine schemes is equivalent to the category of commutative rings (with unit). In particular we have a bijection of sets

$$\mbox{Hom}_{\mathfrak{Rings}}(A,B) \leftrightarrow \mbox{Hom}_{\mathfrak{ScH}}(\mbox{Spec}(B),\mbox{Spec}(A)).$$

defined as follows. For any $\varphi : \mbox{Spec}(B) \to \mbox{Spec}(A)$ we have an associated map on sheaves $\varphi^{\sharp} : \mathcal{O}_{\mbox{Spec}(A)} \to \varphi_\ast \mathcal{O}_{\mbox{Spec}(B)}$. Taking global sections we obtain a ring homomorphism $A \to B$. Now consider the case $A = B$. Because the the identity map $f : A \to A$ induces the identity map on $\mbox{Spec}(A)$, then whatever map that induces the identity on the spectra has to be the identity (by injectivity of the correspondence above).

**Edit:** I should clarify that in my answer above I am treating $\operatorname{Spec} A$ as an affine scheme with its structure sheaf and not just as a topological space. In the latter case my answer will not be true anymore; take $A = k(x)$ that has automorphism group $\mbox{PGL}(2)$.

Answer (score 3):

The question is ambiguous.  Do you mean to assume that $\hat{f}$ is the identity on the *topological space* $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ or on the *scheme* (or ringed space) $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$?  If the former, then any non-identity automorphism of a field provides a counterexample.  If the latter, BenjaLim's answer applies.

Comment: YACP:  Fair enough.  Editing to add the adjective "non-identity".